# How to pause an iteration using $q service?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use $q service for making a pause in the iteration because I have a condition of making API calls in loop.

I've used following approach:

```
function getData(id){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var data;
   Restangular.all("some/api").post(id)
       .then(function (result) {
            data = result;
            doSomeFurtheProcessingWithData(data);
            console.log("Data fetched for "+id);
            deferred.resolve(data);
         }, function(error) {
              deferred.resolve(data);
         });
   return deferred.promise;
}

function getDataOneByOne(ids){
   for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
      console.log("Fetching details for "+ ids[i]);
      getData(ids[i]);
   }
}
```

I expect the result to be

> Fetching details for 101
>  Data fetched for 101
>  Fetching details for 102
>   Data fetched for 102
>  Fetching details for 103
>  Data fetched for 103

But the actual result above code gives is

> Fetching details for 101
>  Fetching details for 102
>  Fetching
>   details for 103
>  Data fetched for 101
>  Data fetched for
>   102
>  Data fetched for 103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using await/async to wait for the promise to return before iterating thru the loop? like below

```
function getData(id){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var data;
   Restangular.all("some/api").post(id)
       .then(function (result) {
            data = result;
            doSomeFurtheProcessingWithData(data);
            console.log("Data fetched for "+id);
            deferred.resolve(data);
         }, function(error) {
              deferred.resolve(data);
         });
   return deferred.promise;
}



function getDataOneByOne(ids){
  if(ids.length > 0){
    var id = ids.shift();
    console.log("Fetching details for "+ id);
    getData(id).then(function(){
      getDataOneByOne(ids);
    });

  }

}

getDataOneByOne([1,2,3,4,5,]);
```

Comment: Is there anything to be imported or added? because this gives me error "Expecting newline or semicolon" near the keywords "async" and "await"

Comment: @Diksha Updated the answer. Can you try.

Comment: And what if the "ids" is not just a number and object?

Comment: it depends. if its an array of objects, you could use the same method.

Comment: So when we're using getData(id).then(); do we have any need of using deferred service?

Comment: Yes the '$q.defer()' makes it a promise to use 'then()'

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.hellojs.org/use-reduce-and-promises-to-execute-multiple-async-calls-sequentially-4caf03a34b9a

Use .reduce for resolving promises sequentally.

Comment: Yeah I tried to use reduce but its not just about the sequential resolving I need to do other processing as well id just before the call is made. Is there anything to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be simulated using recursion and global index. async, await solution remains better:

```
   var index = 0; 
   function getDataOneByOne(ids){
       if (index >= ids.length){
          return;
       }
       console.log("Fetching details for "+ ids[index]);
       getData(ids[index]).then(function () {
           index++;
           getDataOneByOne(ids);
       });
    }
```